# Translating between Set Theoretic and Interval notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation

Given an open interval (or closed it makes little difference to the question) on the Real Field $(a, b)$, where $a,b$ are real numbers, and an arbitrary predicate $P(x)$, which is true for all elements of the interval.

Using Set Theory Notation, I can represent what I've described in the following way.

$$P(x) \  \forall \ x \in \{x \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R} \ \land \ a < x < b \}$$

Using Interval Notation, however what is the *correct* way to translate from Set Theory to Interval Notation. **Which of the following options would you say are correct?** (*no this is **NOT** homework, these are a list of different commonly used styles of interval notation, I've come across*)

1. $P(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \ (a, b)$
2. $P(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}  \in (a, b)$
3. $P(x) \ \forall x \in (a, b)$

---

*Option 1*, is what I tend to commonly use, but I've come to realize that it may cause confusion as   "$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$" is commonly used to represent the interval $(-\infty, \infty)$.

*Option 2* seems to be the most explicit, as it shows that $x$ is an element of the Real Field, and lies within the interval $(a, b)$. Furthermore it can be used to construct more complicated statements such as the following :

$P(x) \ \forall x \in \mathbb{Q}  \in (a, b)$, which would mean a predicate would hold true for all rational numbers within the interval on the Real Field, between the real numbers $a, b$

*Option 3* is what I see used most often, however it seems to be the least explicit, as it does not even denote the Set (Field in this case), which $x$ belongs do. Yes, it says that $x$ is an element of the interval $(a, b)$, but $x$ could be a complex number, integer, rational, irrational or real, as we haven't specified explicitly, which field $x$ is an element of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 3 is by far the most common, as you say. It is almost always used to refer to $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a < x < b \}$. It doesn't even make sense to consider an interval in $\mathbb{C}$, because there is no order on $\mathbb{C}$ that respects the field structure. Your Option 1 is so non-standard that I would ask for clarification if I saw it and had the option of asking for clarification. Option 2 is written in such a way that it appears false: $\mathbb{R} \not \in (a,b)$.

In the absence of further clarification, $x \in (a,b)$ essentially always means $a < x < b$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. If you wish to say something else, you might say "$x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (a,b)$" or whatever, and of course if you're working in a different total order than $(\mathbb{R}, <)$ then the interval notation will refer to intervals in that order.

There are special cases where you can emphasise that you're in $\mathbb{R}$: it's fairly close to standard to write $\mathbb{R}^{>0}$ for the strictly positive reals, for instance. Usually best to stick to $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: a<x<b\}$ if you need to be explicit, though.